# How to change datetime format from some different string format in one way? python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataset with some different input string format of datetime, such as:
Jan-11, Feb-11, Mar-11, .., Des-11
Jan 11, Feb 11, Mar 11, .., Des 11
Jan'11, Feb'11, Mar'11, .., Des'11
Jan-12, Feb-12, Mar-12, .., Des-12
Jan 12, Feb 12, Mar 12, .., Des 12
Jan'12, Feb'12, Mar'12, .., Des'12
Jan-13, Feb-13, Mar-13, .., Des-13
Jan 13, Feb 13, Mar 13, .., Des 13
Jan'13, Feb'13, Mar'13, .., Des'13

```
date_string = "Jan-11"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%b-%d")
date_string_2 = "Jan 11"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string_2, "%b-%d")
date_string_3 = "Jan'11"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string_3, "%b %d")
date_string_4 = "Jan-12"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string_4, "%b-%d")
date_string_5 = "Jan 12"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string_5, "%b-%d")
date_string_6 = "Jan'12"
date = datetime.strptime(date_string_6, "%b %d")
```

and so on.

How can I do change that in one way?

Comment: could you clarify your desired output ?

Comment: I wanna all format to be "%b-%d"

Answer (score -1):

You could try utilizing a list, and then using a for loop to do
`date = datetime.strptime(date_string_4, "%b-%d")`
over and over again.

```py
for i in range (list length + 1 goes here):
    date = datetime.strptime(list[i], "%b-%d")
```

Comment: so I should make a list which contains all string format from my dataset, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think that should work (and make your life easier).